# Programmed completion in minibuffer

Tags: completion

I can read a string in the minibuffer, with completion, using `completing-read`:

```lisp
(completing-read "Chose one: " '("Han Solo" "Chewbacca" "Lando Calrissian"))
```

I would like to use my own completion function, which searches some of my files, instead of a list. The [Programmed Completion page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Programmed-Completion.html) of the manual details just how to do that, but does not give any example.

The best I could achieve is this :

```lisp
(defun completion-function (input-string predicate flag)
  (if flag
      '("Chewbacca" "C3-PO" "Calrissian")
  "C3-PO"))

(completing-read "Chose one: " 'completion-function)
```

However, this does not behave at all like I would :

- it suggests only one choice on the first `TAB` press (I would like all of them to be shown, as what shows a second `TAB` push)
- it does not filter the results on the input string (do I need to implement that as well?)

Can someone give a better, more complete example?

Answer (score 4):

Your `completion-function` is a function, but not a proper completion table (it does not obey all the expected behavior).

I recommend you use `completion-table-dynamic` to build a proper completion table function from a function that simply lists all the possible completions.

E.g.

```
(defun my-completion-function (prefix)
  ;; You can just ignore the prefix
  '("Chewbacca" "C3-PO" "Calrissian"))

(completing-read "Chose one: "
                 (completion-table-dynamic #'my-completion-function))
```